# How to position a div in bottom right corner of a browser?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I am trying to place my div with some notes in the **bottom right** position of the screen which will be displayed all time.

I used following css for it:

```
#foo
{
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
}
```

It works fine with Chrome 3 and Firefox 3.6 but IE8 sucks...

what can be a suitable solution for it?

Comment: What DOCTYPE are you using? Thinking of IEs "compatibility" modes

Comment: none... which should be used?

Comment: In relation to your IE6 comment below, IE6 does not understand `position:fixed;`. So what you do is have a wrapper div that has `position:relative;` filling the whole screen and then you position the div you want with `position:absolute;`. If however your site scrolls down you need to use CSS expressions in IE6 to keep the div docked to the bottom right corner.

Comment: thnx for the information. regarding IE 6 them i would better leave it alone... :P where can i fnd that css expression

Answer (score 150, accepted):

This snippet works in IE7 at least

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test</title>
<style>
  #foo {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="foo">Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why does this not work for me unless I remove the "`<!DOCTYPE html>`"?

Comment: Works for chrome as well!

Answer (score 19):

I don't have IE8 to test this out, but I'm pretty sure it should work:

```
<div class="screen">
   <!-- code -->
   <div class="innerdiv">
      text or other content
   </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.screen{
position: relative;
}
.innerdiv {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

This should place the .innerdiv in the bottom-right corner of the .screen class.
I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
#foo
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0%;
}
```

Comment: I think that will make the top edge below the bottom edge of the parent element.

Comment: No. 100% is screen.height - element.height.