# CSS - Position to bottom right?

Tags: css

How do i make this position to bottom right?

**HTML**

```
<div class="info player">
            <div id="job" style="display:none;"><span>Jobname</span></div>
            <div id="status">
                <ul>
                    <li class="icon" id="thirst" style="display:none;"><i class="fas fa-tint"></i><span></span></li>
                    <li class="icon" id="hunger" style="display:none;"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i><span></span></li>
                    <li class="icon" id="stamina" style="display:none;"><i class="fas fa-running"></i><span></span></li>
                    <li class="icon" id="armor" style="display:none;"><i class="fas fa-shield-alt"></i><span></span></li>
                    <li class="icon" id="health" style="display:none;"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i><span></span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.info { position: absolute; }

.info.server { bottom: 0; right: 0; }
.info.server #server img { max-width: 100%; opacity: 0.75; }

.info.player { bottom: 0; right: 0; text-align: right;}
.info.player #job span { font-size: 20px; color: #FFF; font-weight: 900; text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); }

.info.player #status { clear: both; }
.info.player #status ul { margin: 1px 0 0 0; }
.info.player #status ul li { float: right;}
.info.player #status ul li#health span { background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff0000 0%, #aa0000 100%); }
.info.player #status ul li#armor span { background: linear-gradient(180deg, #0bcfe6 0%, #0aa3b5 100%); }
.info.player #status ul li#stamina span { background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffb700 0%, #e0a102 100%); }
.info.player #status ul li#hunger span { background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff8000 0%, #cd6700 100%); }
.info.player #status ul li#thirst span { background: linear-gradient(180deg, #00c3ff 0%, #008fbb 100%); }
.info.player #status ul li#health.dead { animation: trew-pulse 500ms infinite; }
.info.player #status ul li#health.dead span { height: 0 !important; }
.info.player #status ul li#health.dead i.fas:before { content: '\f714'; }
```

After i change on  ***.info.server*** and ***.info.player*** to bottom right, they are still visible at the top left.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3616572 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/3616572/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/18998888

Comment: You don't have a closing `</div>` tag (from the `<div class="info player">` tag

Answer (score 0):

I presume by "this" you mean `<div class="info player">`. If you want it to be stuck in bottom right corner of the window (or relatively inside other element, it's not clear from your snippet), just add `position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;` to `.info.player` selector and make sure nothing overrides it.